# YII CGridView. Trying to show attribute from other table. Relation not working

Tags: php, mysql, yii, foreign-key-relationship, cgridview

This is driving me nuts. I read many responses and tutorials and i can't pin point the problem here.

I have 2 Tables: **tblEmpleado** and **tblProfesion** [Here is an image of the MySQL relations they have (Marked on red)](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/8018/flvk.png)

I want to display on a `CGridView` the attribute "Descripcion" from the table **tblProfesion** when displaying the data from **tblEmpleado**.

I tried using claveProfesion.descripcion without avail (It shows the INT number of the FK just fine without the ".descripcion" part). Also tried using something like:

> array(
>       'header'=>'tableHeaderName',
>       'value'=>'(isset($data->claveProfesion)) ? $data->claveProfesion->descripcion : null', )

getting "Trying to get property of non-object".

Here is the Empleados.php relation part of the model code:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tblcelulars' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tblcelular', 'claveEmpleado'),
        'tblcuentabancos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tblcuentabanco', 'claveEmpleado'),
        'idCentroTrabajo' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblcentrotrabajo', 'idCentroTrabajo'),
        'convenio' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblconvenio', 'convenio'),
        'claveProfesion' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblprofesion', 'claveProfesion'),
    );
}
```

And the CGridView part of the Admin.php View code

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'empleados-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'claveEmpleado',
        'nombreEmpleado',
        'idCentroTrabajo',
        array(
                'header'=>'tableHeaderName',
                'value'=>'($data->claveProfesion!=null) ? $data->claveProfesion->descripcion : null',
        ),
        'aniosExperiencia',
        'telefono2',
        'email',
...
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

And last, i don't know if its related but in the Model class `"Profesiones.php"` the relation is as follow:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tblempleados' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tblempleado', 'claveProfesion'),
    );
}
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: show code of `model->search()` since you use it as dataProvider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column and your relation both have the same name `claveProfesion`. As such Yii is returning the column instead of the relation when you call `claveProfesion`. To resolve it rename your relation to something else e.g `claveProfesionObject`

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'claveProfesionObject' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblprofesion', 'claveProfesion'),
    );
}
```

Comment: That's whats it! Thanks!

Damn, how come i didn't think it before?